# .htacess specifying specific files on one line

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in part of my .htaccess file:

```
# the following prevents display of the filetohide file
<files handler.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

<files submit.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

Can multiple file specifiers not be done within a single set of tags, i.e:

```
<files submit.php|handler.php|otherfile.txt>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, if this helps you for multiple file names with different formats(I am yet to test this but written this based on regex).

```
<files ~ "^((submit|handler)\.php)$|^(otherfile\.txt)$">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. I did a third file too as:<files ~ "^((submit|handler)\.php)$|^(data_base_update\.txt)|^(thingsdata\.txt)$">